# Docker for MAC | Cannot run program "docker-credential-desktop"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-desktop

I'm trying to create a Docker image on a Mac computer. The command fails with the following error. I'm on Docker Desktop version 2.2.05.

```
Cannot run program "docker-credential-desktop": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've read on some forums that including "credsStore": "osxkeychain" or "credsStore": "desktop" in ~/.docker/config.json. fixes the problem but I'm not able to find this file.

Has anybody faced this issue before? Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: May you share how you are trying to create that docker image? What command are you exactly running?

Answer (score 26):

If you are trying to use with Spring Boot - fabric8 plugin and on mac machine do the following :

In ~/.docker/config.json change **credsStore to credStore**

Comment: thanks this works, please provide an explanation why.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: This worked for me, although now I'll occasionally get the same error, and when I look at that file there's both credStore and credsStore, I just delete the credsStore and then it works again.

Comment: Thanks it resolved my issue and for windows also it is working.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS this file is located in:
`/Users/YourUserName/.docker/config.json`

The content of this file should look like this:

```
{
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "auths" : {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/" : {

    }
  },
  "credsStore" : "desktop",
  "experimental" : "disabled"
}
```